# Why is .click() not working in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript

Alright so I'm starting to learn how to build chrome extensions so i can automate some tasks at work.

I Set up my manifest.json file as follows:

```
    {
"manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],

            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

my content.js file seems to be working fine, when I console.log() stuff it shows up in the website's console. However, when I try to use the .click(); method with query selector, it shows an error.

```
var this_button = document.querySelector(".nav-link"); this_button[0].click();
```

The error shown when I try to load the Extension is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

the websites console reads this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

Any ideas? I am not using Jquery and cannot use it for this project, as I cannot download anything external onto work computer. This needs to be done with Vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this_button[0].click()` is incorrect - you should be using `this_button.click()`